# Counting date in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I write query to check if the last day is Friday but always I see 2 not 4.
Any advice what is wrong with that query ?

```
 (
 SELECT (
        CASE
               WHEN To_char(due_date,'DAY','nls_date_language=english')='FRIDAY' THEN 4
               ELSE 2
        END)
 FROM   capagency.pa_instances pa,
        capagency.users u
 WHERE  pa.idusr = u.idusr
 AND    pa.entity_id = a.ceid
 AND    p.payment_date BETWEEN pa.begin_date AND    pa.due_date.
```

Ok, i added trim but that still results that i obtain are wrong, instead of value 4 i got value 2.

```
(
select convert(u.Full_Name, 'UTF8')
from Capagency.Pa_Instances Pa,
     Capagency.Users u
where Pa.Idusr = u.Idusr
AND Pa.Entity_Id = a.Ceid
and p.payment_date BETWEEN pa.begin_Date and Pa.DUE_DATE + (
    CASE WHEN (TRIM(TO_CHAR(due_date,'DAY','nls_date_language=english'))='FRIDAY')
      THEN 4 ELSE 2 END)
and rownum = 1
) "Collector",
```

First I'm getting

```
(select case
  when (TRIM(To_char(due_date,'DAY','nls_date_language=english'))) = 'FRIDAY'
    THEN 4 else 2 END
from Capagency.Pa_Instances Pa,
     Capagency.Users u
where Pa.Idusr = u.Idusr
AND Pa.Entity_Id = a.Ceid
and p.payment_date BETWEEN pa.begin_Date and Pa.DUE_DATE
```

So I see that day is Friday but still getting value 2 from the `else`. I know how `between` works, and for some days that aren't Friday that works OK, I obtain the correct values.

I'm wondering still why if I check

```
case when (TRIM(To_char(due_date,'DAY','nls_date_language=english'))) = 'FRIDAY'
```

it is always false so my value is always 2 not 4.

Comment: Define "doesn't work"? Does the `case when (trim(...))` bit still not return 4 when the due date is a Friday? Or are you saying you're not getting the expected results from your query? If the latter, then you'll have to go through each of your predicates one-by-one to make sure you understand what they're doing. My guess is that the `rownum = 1` is not doing what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: You can see the date adjustments being made by running that on its own; [here's a demo covering a three-week period](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40560). Further to Boneist's comment, also check that `between` is doing what you think here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs,

DAY format model -

> Name of day, padded with blanks to display width of the widest name of
>   day in the date language used for this element.

You need to **TRIM** the spaces right padded to the **DAY** format. Modify your query to -

`TRIM(To_char(due_date,'DAY','nls_date_language=english'))='FRIDAY'`

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT LENGTH(trim(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN'))) dt_trim,
  2    LENGTH(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN')) dt,
  3    TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') DAY
  4  FROM emp
  5  /

   DT_TRIM         DT DAY
---------- ---------- ---------
         9          9 WEDNESDAY
         6          9 FRIDAY
         6          9 SUNDAY
         8          9 THURSDAY
         6          9 MONDAY
         6          9 FRIDAY
         7          9 TUESDAY
         8          9 THURSDAY
         7          9 TUESDAY
         7          9 TUESDAY
         9          9 WEDNESDAY

   DT_TRIM         DT DAY
---------- ---------- ---------
         8          9 THURSDAY
         8          9 THURSDAY
         8          9 SATURDAY

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

So you see the spaces right padded to the `DAY` column? I would say better use `DY` format, which has only 3 characters.

Or, use **TRIM**. Let's look at a similar test case using **HIREDATE** column in **EMP** table -

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN trim(TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN'))='FRIDAY'
  4      THEN 4
  5      ELSE 2
  6    END dt,
  7    TO_CHAR(hiredate, 'DAY', 'nls_date_language=AMERICAN') dt_1
  8  FROM emp
  9  /

        DT DT_1
---------- ---------
         2 WEDNESDAY
         4 FRIDAY
         2 SUNDAY
         2 THURSDAY
         2 MONDAY
         4 FRIDAY
         2 TUESDAY
         2 THURSDAY
         2 TUESDAY
         2 TUESDAY
         2 WEDNESDAY

        DT DT_1
---------- ---------
         2 THURSDAY
         2 THURSDAY
         2 SATURDAY

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should hopefully demonstrate what's going on:

```
select to_char(to_date('13/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY','nls_date_language=english') dy,
       replace(to_char(to_date('13/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'DAY','nls_date_language=english'), ' ', '*') dy_show_spaces,
       to_char(to_date('13/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'fmDAY','nls_date_language=english') fmdy,
       replace(to_char(to_date('13/02/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'fmDAY','nls_date_language=english'), ' ', '*') fmdy_show_spaces
from   dual;

DY        DY_SHOW_SPACES FMDY   FMDY_SHOW_SPACES
--------- -------------- ------ ----------------
FRIDAY    FRIDAY***      FRIDAY FRIDAY
```

See [also](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216).

In short, the `fm` modifier negates the need to use `TRIM` on the resultant string.

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it.